# "Initializing" a constant containing a file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that initializing variables/constants in python is not necessary, but my professor still wants us to initialize variables for practice.

In my program, I have a file to which I assigned a name:

```
infile = open("studentinfo.txt", "r")
```

How would it make sense to initialize the constant "infile"? Can I initialize it as an empty string, or should I do it as an empty file maybe?

Comment: "to initialize variables for practice" — Practising *what*?  Pointless boilerplate?

Comment: @jwodder haha it's supposed to be practice for when (if) we take classes on other languages

Comment: BTW: when working with files you almost never assign them to a variable. You always tend to use them via the `with` statement: `with open(...) as f: for line in f: print(line)`. In this way the file is automatically closed at the end of the block and you don't have to worry for a missing call to `.close()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach in Python is to initialize a variable to `None` if it is not being used yet. This is a signal to the future readers of your code that you want that variable to exist, but it won't be until later that it is used.

```
infile = None
```

In this way, throughout the rest of your code, you can check whether the value is set yet ...

```
if infile is None:
  infile = open(filename, 'r')
with infile:
  data = infile.read()
```

This approach saves you from type-checking (uglly) and you know that if `infile` is not `None` then it must be a file, therefore you use it as just a file ("duck typing"). For example, elsewhere in the code you may have ...

```
if infile:
  data = infile.read(1024)
else:
  data = ''
```

This is very readable and nothing breaks if the file was never set.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, when we want to set a variable to "no value in particular," we use `None`:

```
infile = None
# ...several lines later...
infile = open(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your professor wants you to get used to static-typing for future languages in which case I would use `infile=str()` to ensure that python views it as a string.  This also most closely mimics the syntax of other languages, unlike say: `infile=''`.  If you wanted an empty file type `infile = file()`.

Answer (score 0):

Files are [objects](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-file-object).  How about `None`?

Filenames are probably [strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string).  `filename = str()` or `filename = None` again.

```
filename = str()

# or...
filename = None
infile = open(filename, 'r')
```